# Associating Different URLS

Tags: google-analytics, pageviews

Let's say I used to have a page /about.html for a period of time and GA tracked pageviews for that page.

Now the url changed to /about-us.html. Is there any way, through GA's platform, or through the js snippet, to associate /about-us.html pageviews with the old data collected for /about.html?

The idea is not to lose the already collected data for pages whose urls changed. I know that there is no reprocessing with GA, but perhaps data correlation is possible after the fact?

Comment: You can use the page title, provided that hasn't changed either. There is a tiny navigation above the data tables where you can select the primary dimension that is used for the report. But if this is about how to do things in the interface this is off-topic and should probably go to webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks Eike, I'll head over to webmasters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just about viewing the say the total number of pw to that page with two urls you could create a custom dimension and use a regular expression that include both versions. Or simpler you could just use the filter in GA and use regexmatch in the "All pages" report for the page dimension.

/about.html, /about-us.html

**The regex filter can look like:** ^\/about(|-us)\.html$

How does that work?

Comment: Thank you Maarten, I will look into your answer.

Comment: Sound like a filter would work for you in the all pages report.